# Unable to seek FLV video

Tags: linux, video, vlc-media-player, mplayer, flv

I can not seek flv video downloaded by `rtmpsuck`. Tried `MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7` and `vlc (2.1.2-0-ga4c4876)`.

```
$ mplayer2 video.flv
MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team

Playing video.flv.
Detected file format: FLV (Flash Video) (libavformat)
[lavf] stream 0: video (flv), -vid 0
[lavf] stream 1: audio (mp3), -aid 0
Clip info:
 hasKeyframes: true
 hasVideo: true
 canSeekToEnd: false
 datasize: 227663016
 lasttimestamp: 4126
 audiosize: 99750762
 hasAudio: true
 audiodelay: 0
 videosize: 127907046
 metadatacreator: inlet media FLVTool2 v1.0.6 - http://www.inlet-media.de/flvtool2
 lastkeyframetimestamp: 4125
 hasMetadata: true
 hasCuePoints: false
Selected video codec: FLV / Sorenson Spark / Sorenson H.263 (Flash Video) [libavcodec]
Selected audio codec: MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 layers I, II, III [mpg123]
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 32.0 kbit/2.27% (ratio: 4000->176400)
AO: [alsa] 48000Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
VIDEO:  1440x900  1000.000 fps  252.6 kbps (31.6 kB/s)
VO: [xv] 1440x900 => 1440x900 Planar YV12 
Colorspace details not fully supported by selected vo.
A: ???   V:  13.4 A-V: -0.001 ct:  0.000   0/  0 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0 


Exiting... (End of file)
```

mplayer will close, VLC remains open, but with black screen:

```
$ vlc video.flv
VLC media player 2.1.2 Rincewind (revision 2.1.2-0-ga4c4876)
...
[flv @ 0x7fe8a8c09c60] Unsupported video codec (0)
[flv @ 0x7fe8a8fffdc0] Bad picture start code
[flv @ 0x7fe8a8fffdc0] header damaged
[flv @ 0x7fe8a8c09c60] Stream discovered after head already parsed
Truncating packet of size 16259399 to 169421
```

Re encoding to another format helps, but it takes time. Another fix? *nix compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flv was crippled. `[flv @ 0x7fe8a8fffdc0] header damaged`

It's not necessary to re-encode it to another codec/format, just rebuild it.

I rebuilt the video with `ffmpeg`, audio and video codecs copied:

```
$ ffmpeg -i video.flv -c:v copy -c:a copy fixed.flv
...
[flv @ 0x63ff80] Found invalid index entries, clearing the index.
```

Took fraction of time compared to re-encoding f.e. to x264.